# One-click automated USB trash delete

Tags: finder, usb, automator, trash

Is there any way I can create an automator service or app to delete ALL trash from any USB drive (my own account's trash plus everybody else's)?

I've read several solutions involving Terminal, including [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6434/emptying-trash-of-the-usb-drive), but I'd like something a bit more foolproof and really handy.

I need to exchange USB drives regularly for presentations at events and Mac trash is becoming a problem as Macs become more common -- people suddenly get "no space available" error messages and can't do anything about it. I know how to skip the trash, but need a quick fix when the trash is already there.

Comment: Whats wrong with emptying the Trash in the regular way?

Comment: like bin/bash+Trash and its gone :)

Answer (score 2):

2 Solutions. 1 using Bash the other using Bash wrapped in AppleScript.

### Solution #1

1. Create a new AppleScript with `/Applications/Utilities/AppleScript Editor`
2. Type the following code:

   ```
   do shell script "rm -rf /Volumes/*/.Trashes/*" with administrator privileges
   ```
3. Save the file to somewhere convenient and run it whenever you need to clear the USB Trash
4. This can be executed by double-clicking on it

**NOTE:** This will empty the Trash for all connected volumes including your internal hard disk. If you have connected 5 USB drives and a Firewire hard disk, it will empty the trash for all of them.

---

### Solution #2

1. Fire up your favourite text editor *(mine is nano)*
2. Paste the following code into your text editor and save the file

   ```
   #!/bin/bash  
   sudo rm -rf /Volumes/*/.Trashes/*
   ```
3. Save the file to somewhere convenient with the extension `.sh` and then make it executable with `chmod +x {filename}.sh` from Terminal
4. Run that with `./{filename}.sh`

**NOTE:** Same note as above. This is executable from Terminal.

Comment: Why do you escape the `*`s?

Comment: I fixed it up. It was because before I was editing in a different visual editor, and needed the escape character on them or it bolded the text or something stupid in between.

Answer (score 0):

Using Automator :

- Create a new Service with automator
- Change *Service receives selected* to files and folders
- Change pass input to “as arguments” from “stdin”
- Add a **Run ShellScript** action

Use this script

```
find /Volumes/ -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 | grep .Trashes | xargs rm -R
```

- Save your new service

It will be accessible from the right clic under the name you saved it.